# how can I get a previous row value in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a df like this

```
|  count  | A |  
|---------|---|
|  yes    |2  |
|  yes    |2  |  
|  total  |   |  
|  yes    |2  |  
|  yes    |2  | 
|  total  |   |
```

I want a output like below

```
|  count  | A |  
|---------|---|
|  yes    |2  |
|  yes    |2  |  
|  total  | 2  |  
|  yes    |2  |  
|  yes    |2  | 
|  total  | 2  |
```

that is fill the A column values where there is total with the previous row value
any idea how can I achieve this

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong with your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `df.loc` and `series.mask` and `ffill`

```
df.loc[df['count'].eq("total"),"A"] = df['A'].mask(df['A'].eq('')).ffill()
```

---

```
print(df)

   count  A
0    yes  2
1    yes  2
2  total  2
3    yes  2
4    yes  2
5  total  2
```

Comment: Thanks alot anky , saved my time

Comment: @PriyaChauhan Glad to help ..!!  I am certain you might have tried something which did not work as you intended. If you can please post that in future, that'd be appreciated  This helps SO users to correct you instead of solving the problem for you.. Its a win win ..!! ;)

Comment: Sure @anky,, I was trying this with pandas shift function, but didn't arrived at a solution

Comment: @PriyaChauhan Np :) I am sure you will consider this in future. happy coding !!